# Know when child element has loaded

Tags: aurelia, custom-element

I've created three Google Map related elements in Aurelia, and I'm using them in a nested fashion where I have a base `GoogleMap` element, and on top of that I have a `GoogleMapLocationPicker` element and on top of *that* a `GoogleMapAutocomplete` element.

This all works mostly fine, *but* the problem I'm having is that when I try to access my child `GoogleMap` element from within my `GoogleMapAutocomplete` element I have to put my code in an arbitrary `setTimeout` or I get errors for trying to access non-existent properties.

I really don't like just slapping 200ms on a `setTimeout` and hope it never fails, so I'd like to know if there's some official way of knowing when my child elements have loaded? (Without using the `EventAggregator` which I might do as a last resort).

I basically have this (please note the code is extremely simplified and in some cases outright incorrect, but this is for demonstration purposes only - the actual google maps code works fine):

**google-map**

```
export class GoogleMap {
    @bindable markers;

    constructor () {
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.element);

        this.markers.forEach((marker) => {
            this.addMarker(marker);
        });
    }
}

<template>
    <div class="google-map"></div>
</template>
```

**google-map-location-picker**

```
export class GoogleMapLocationPicker {
    constructor {
        this.markers = [{
            draggable: true,
            dragend: e => {
                alert('Nice drag');
            }
        }];
    }
}

<template>
    <google-map markers.bind="markers" view-model.ref="map"></google-map>
</template>
```

**google-map-autocomplete**

```
export class GoogleMapAutocomplete {
    constructor () {
        this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete();

        // This fails unless I wait like 200ms because GoogleMap hasn't yet created its map
        this.map.map.map.controls.push(this.autocomplete);
    }
}

<template>
    <google-map-location-picker view-model.ref="map"></google-map-location-picker>
</template>
```

**Update:**

I've created a Plunker to further explain this: http://plnkr.co/edit/8fVbjZhJoC8tzAfQOmKP?p=preview

As you can see App includes `<parent-element>` (in my case this would be the `GoogleMapAutocomplete` for example) and it in turn includes a `<child-element>` (in my case `GoogleMap`).

The child element does some async stuff and only after that is complete can I access properties of the child from the parent. As you can see in `parent-element.js` trying to alert the child's property returns `undefined`.

How can I, from `parent-element.js`, know when `child-element.js` has finished all its async stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest solution here might be to dispatch a CustomEvent when the child-element is done, then .delegate that to the parent-element, like so:

(I've taken your plunkr as the basis)

In **child-element.js**:

```
import { inject } from "aurelia-framework";

@inject(Element)
export class ChildElement {
  constructor (element) {
    this.isLoaded = false;
    this.element = element;
  }

  attached () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isLoaded = true;
      this.aPropertyOnlyAvailableAfterLoadingIsComplete = true;
      this.element.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("loaded", {
          bubbles: true
      }));
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

In **parent-element.html**:

```
<child-element view-model.ref="child" loaded.delegate="onChildLoaded($event)">
</child-element>
```

In **parent-element.js**:

```
onChildLoaded($event) {
    alert(this.child.aPropertyOnlyAvailableAfterLoadingIsComplete);
}
```

See [this gist](https://gist.run/?id=16e2eb80c1ebe8e66bca213574f19a28) for a running version

**EDIT (Event Aggregator vs CustomEvent)**

Your comment regarding the difference between using Event Aggregator and a CustomEvent is an important question, so I'll answer it here.

The blog post [working with the aurelia event aggregator](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/02/working-with-the-aurelia-event-aggregator/) gives some additional pointers:

> It allows you to fire off events that **don’t have a specific target**,
>   events potentially multiple listeners could be looking out for. They
>   are not essential, they are like observers, when something happens the
>   subscriber methods are notified and allow you to act accordingly.
>
> Everything comes with a cost, so **don’t abuse it and use it for every
>   change in your application**, it is very much for those situations where
>   cross component communication is essential.

1. events that don't have a specific target

In this case, your target is the parent of a certain element. That's a very specific target and should be an indicator that a CustomEvent is probably the best fit.

2. don't use it for every change in your application

It's easy to use the Event Aggregator for every change in your application. All of it will just work. Aside from potential timing issues with components that depend on it (like aurelia-router), overusing the Event Aggregator will reduce cohesion between closely related components for little to no gain.

I would like to add to that:

3. Use a CustomEvent when the components are tightly coupled / closely related, and Event Aggregator when they loosely coupled
4. Use a CustomEvent when the components are tied to the DOM (such as custom elements), and Event Aggregator when they are not (such as stand-alone modules/classes, in which case a CustomEvent cannot be used)
5. For DOM-tied components where a CustomEvent cannot solve your problem in a clean, straight-forward manner (for example with sibling elements), the Event Aggregator may be a better idea
6. Using the Event Aggregator means you have subscriptions to dispose, which adds work and complexity.
7. The Event Aggregator is a dependency you need to import, while CustomEvents are native to JavaScript

CustomEvents are usually simpler to implement/manage and have clearer limitations in their use. They also make the views more readable (consider `some-event.delegate="onSomeEvent"` versus having to scan through both classes for publish/subscribe methods and their keys + handlers).

For this reason I tend to start with a CustomEvent, and only if it doesn't work / gets too complex, I resort to the Event Aggregator.

Comment: Thanks. Would you say a `CustomEvent` is better than Aurelia's `EventAggregator` in this case? Could you explain why if so? (I would like to learn the difference and benefits of both).

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use the `if.bind` function. I'm not sure which of your elements depend on the other, but it sounds like autocomplete and location picker depend on the base GoogleMap to be rendered. So, what I've done with my projects is declare a `InitDataLoaded = false` in my vm. Then, once I've loaded all of the initial data, I'll change that to `true`. And in the html I'll do `<myComponent if.bind="InitDataLoaded"></myComponent>`

You'll have to tweak it of course, but I think `if.bind` is your route to take. It only renders the element if the condition is true.

To further explain what **I (myself)** would do:

I would add that `InitDataLoaded` boolean in my main GoogleMaps component. Then in the constructor, after you do all the stuff needed to initially kick off the component, change that boolean from a `false` to a `true`.

Now, in your locationpicker and autocomplete, I would use `@autoinject` or `@inject` to inject an instance of the GoogleMaps component into the vm. From there, you can access that `InitDataLoaded` variable and use the `if.bind` to render the component only if that boolean is `true`.

I've added a Gist of a working sample without the use of a timeout. https://gist.run/?id=2e02bc4cc7236093937b964b5f546be0

Comment: But if I do `if.bind` on `<google-map-autocomplete>` surely its child elements won't render either?

Comment: @powerbuoy I just edited my answer to explain what I would do if I were in your shoes. You're right, it wouldn't render any child element of <google-map-autocomplete> but why would you want to render it before the dependent component isn't rendered?

Comment: I will need to try this out to verify this solves my problem. The issue now is that I rewrote all my components to NOT inherit from each other :P

But what you're saying is that in my GoogleMap child component I'll have a property like `isLoaded` and then I'll check that property from my parent ? I don't really see how I can use `if.bind` though because I don't want to _not_ render my component (which would cause its children not to render either and thus `isLoaded` would never be true).

Comment: I could be missing something here but here's what I see from what you've said above. You have a main component (GoogleMaps). You have 2 child components (LocationPicker) and (Autocomplete). In my eyes, there's no way that these 2 child components can be used without the base component, so why would you not make the child components depend on the GoogleMaps component? For example, why would you want the LocationPicker to render if the base component (GoogleMaps) hasn't rendered? There's really no need because you can't do anything without the base component.

Comment: Please have a look at my updated question and the plunker.

Comment: Gotcha. Sort of what I thought. In this case, parent-element is your GoogleMaps base element and the child-element(s) would be your locationpicker and autocomplete. Now, I would have the isLoaded bool in your parent (GoogleMaps) vm. Once google maps base element is loaded and ready to rock, then you change that to true. Now, in your parent-element HTML file, you should have <child-element if.bind="isLoaded">. That will prevent the child elements from being rendered until the base element is ready to go.

Comment: But it's the other way around though. My _parent_ is `GoogleMapAutocomplete` and the child is `GoogleMap`. The parent can't use properties on the child until the child has loaded and it seems like Aurelia (logically I guess) first renders the parent - then its children.

Comment: If you can update the plunker and make `parent-element.js` successfully access the property its trying to access that would be awesome.

Comment: @powerbuoy GistRun is a much easier editor to use with Aurelia. Here's what I would do. Basically, your parent element isn't going to render any of the child elements until it has all of it's data. https://gist.run/?id=2e02bc4cc7236093937b964b5f546be0

Comment: thanks, Gistrun does look better. I appreciate your help, but that code is still sort of the other way around where child loads after the parent. I need the parent to wait for the child. I think Fred's got it.

Comment: @powerbuoy Oh gotcha. Yeah I misunderstood your problem